# file comparison between lines and rows

Tags: bash, awk

I have 3 files, `file1` is a text file, `file2` is a csv file and `file3` is a html file, I need a bash script to do following:

1. Compare the first line of `file1` with second column(config) of `file2` if equal, copy the content of the row into an existing empty table in `file3`
2. If not equal, goto the second line of the second column(config) `file2` then if equal, copy the content of the row into an  existing empty table in `file3`

#### file1: (sample)

```
interface fa0/0
interface loopback 0
ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
router OSPF 1
```

#### file2: (sample)

```
,, Network LAB - Final config - sample -  table 1.1 - CSV - final config table,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,ID,Config,Config description,Config      score,Hostname,Mode,Category,Subcategory,Interface,IP/Network Address (if applicable
,1,interface F0/0,Go to interface F0/0 configuration mode from global configuration mode,0%,R1,Global,Basic config,Int F0/0,F0/0,-
,2,ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0,Set IP address on interface F0/0,8%,R1,Int F0/0,Basic config,Int F0/0 - IP Address,F0/0,10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
,3,no shutdown,Brings interface F0/0 UP,7%,R1,Int F0/0,Basic config,Int F0/0 - Brings UP,F0/0,-
```

#### file3: (This is a table part of the html file)

```
<tr class="gwd-tr-rtto">
<td data-sheets-value="[null,2,&quot;Config&quot;]" class="gwd- td-gn3d">Config</td>
<td data-sheets-value="[null,2,&quot;Config description&quot;]" class="gwd-td-qwup">Config description</td>
<td data-sheets-value="[null,2,&quot;Config score&quot;]" class="gwd-td-d4iw">Config score</td>
<td data-sheets-value="[null,2,&quot;Hostname&quot;]" class="gwd-td-djzd">Hostname</td>
<td data-sheets-value="[null,2,&quot;Mode&quot;]" class="gwd-td-17wt">Mode</td>
<td data-sheets-value="[null,2,&quot;Category&quot;]" class="gwd-td-24v5">Category</td>
```

This is what I have so far, as I have no experience in coding its probably messy and I might totally got it wrong and need to change all of it, appreciate your help.

```
awk   FS=\, OFS=\, '
BEGIN{t="Time , Network LAB"}
FNR==1  {next}
NR==FNR {a[$1];next}
{ 
    if ($1 in a)
       {$1="*"$1;t=t RS $0}
    else
       {s=s==""?$0:s RS $0}
}
END {print t RS s}'file2 file1
awk '{print $0 >> "file3" }
```

Comment: Please show us files 1 and 3, or at least parts thereof.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have edited my question again, if you can help me with this I would be very grateful as this has been a headache in last 2 days, happy to answer your questions.

Comment: @glennjackman can you please help me on this

Comment: So you are going to compare "hostname R1" with "," in file2 and you will find they are not equal and do nothing. Then you will go to the second row of file 2, which is ",,,," and see if that is equal to "hostname R1" which it isn't, so you will do nothing?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok, you right I should add hostname to the table but I have found out I only need to compare file1 to the second column of file2(called "config"). because all the config commands are written in the config section(second column)

Comment: Why do you use `FS="|"` when `file2` is comma separated? (Shouldn't it be `FS=","` ?)

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confused.. What would be the purpose of this statement: `if ($4 FS $5 in a)` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have changed it a little bit, this is pretty much my first code and that is a sample I thought it might relevant to my script as I said it might be totally incorrect. I dont want poeple write the whole script for me. if you can guide me what to do or which feature to use I try to write it myself, Thank you

Comment: Ok, good.. So it is only the first line in `file1` that is relevant for your program? (That is: the line `hostname R1` ? )

Comment: For instance: `ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0` is on line 3 in `file1` and on line 5 in `file2`... But you only want to check the first two rows in `file2`?

Comment: I'm looking at your directions, and they're just not making much sense. Line 1 in `file1` is `hostname R1`. The second column of `file2` says `Config` (which I assume you want to match), but none of those values match `R1` or `hostname R1`. Meanwhile, your directions say _copy the content of the row into an existing empty table in file3_, but there's nothing in `file3` that looks like that row. Can you clarify your directions?

Comment: I have to make it more clear to you, I need to compare all the lines(start from line 1) in file 1 to all the lines (start from line 1) in the 2nd column (called config) in file 2_ if equal copy the row to the 3rd file(any file, does`nt matter) if not equal then move to the second line of csv file and so on until it check all the lines in the config column

Comment: The other thing I have to mention, file 1 is a sample and I have to add hostname to my csv file because its not there at the moment, I just wanted to give you an idea_ copy the result to html file its not my concern now as long as the script forward the result to any file should be ok for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$0]++
    next
  }
  FNR>1{
    if ($3 in a)
        print $3
  }' file1 FS=, file2
```

Output:

```
ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is it going follow an order to the last line of each file?

Comment: Yes config column should be column 3.. due to the leading `,` on each line in `file2`. What do you mean by `follow an order`? Yes it scans all lines in both `file1` and `file2` if that's what you meant..

Comment: for sending the row output if the both files have the same result to the 3rd file can i use this at the end of your script? `awk '{print $0 >> "file3" }`

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but to append the output to `file3` you could change the last line to `}' file1 FS=, file2 >> file3`

Comment: appreciate your time and effort, if I have further guestions or problems can I ask you here?

Comment: Hi Hakon, as I thought there has been slight changes to the script, your last answer is working fine but i was
 looking to compare just one config file(one router) to our main config table(csv file) but I might get a topology more than
 two routers therefore: 1)I must change the script which can compare x number of files to our main config table(csv file) 
2)I must send the result to our html file

Comment: I think if i want to send the result to html file first i have to  
locate where the config will paste. if you look at the html file its a table with different columns and i found two command 
first an script to Find a word and replace it `sed 's/old/new/g' Lab-console.html ` second one is to Find a word and show 
characters after that `grep -oE 'config.{5}' R1.cfg` can you please help me with this one too.

Comment: @user3409828 Hi. I am not sure I understand everything you ask for.. Let's take one thing at a time. First: You say that you have more than one file like `file1`? I cannot see why that is a problem. Then you can just change the file name? Also, maybe you can paste your current script at http://pastebin.com/ ? Then I can have a look at it..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. ok the current script is your last answer, I tested it and it works. imagine we have 5 routers in our topology then I need this script automatically compare all routers config files(Rx.cfg) to our main config table(csv file-which has all the routers name and config command related to the topology). the aim is to tell the user which config command they missed on which device. can i type your answer with different file name together in one go?

Comment: @user3409828 You can try to use a bash script to loop through all router config files.. See for example this script: http://pastebin.com/29z2m1PV (Here, I only used two files to demonstrate, but you can add more if you like..)

Comment: I see, is it working same as last one, compare all the lines in our files to the 3rd column of csv file and if they are the same then print them?

Comment: @user3409828 Yes.. I forgot to mention that `a.awk` is the script in my answer above.. Just save it to a file named `a.awk`.. Here is how the script file (`a.awk`) looks: http://pastebin.com/eDsMTsNM

Comment: so which one should I use bash or awk? I mean your last answer or the new one.

Comment: @user3409828 Both :) Save the bash script as a file `doAll` for example.. Then save the `awk` script as a file `a.awk`.. Make the bash script executable, and run it from the command line..

Comment: Yes I understand now, second need is to send the result to the html file (the html file is an empty table with few rows).

Comment: @user3409828 Great.. Is the html file like `file3` above?

Comment: Yes as you can see we have 6 columns Config/Config description  /Config score /Hostname /Mode/Category

Comment: @user3409828 Yes.. How do you want to do it? For instance, assume  the output of the script is `ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0`..

Comment: Well this a table which tells the user which command in which device is missing, I guess we need to check other columns like hostname in our last script, isnt it?

Comment: @user3409828 I am not sure what you mean.. How do you want the resulting table to look like? Can you paste an example at http://pastebin.com/

Comment: The ip address should go to config column then we need the hotname and the rest_all this columns are in our csv file as wll I assume I should tell the script to check those columns too, what do u think

Comment: @user3409828 So you want to replace the word `>Config</td>` in the table row with `>ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0</td>` ?

Comment: I assume that is how this works, locate the right column and replace it with the result. am I right?

Comment: @user3409828 I do not know :) But let's try that.. Is the missing lines for each config file different?

Comment: I hope I am not confusing you that is the level of my knowledge about scripting I am a cisco certified.

Comment: Well it depend to the user which command they missing, but the answer is likely yes

Comment: @user3409828 You say: `the aim is to tell the user which config command they missed on which device`.. I am not sure I understand this, now it looks like we are finding not the commands they missed but the commands they remembered?

Comment: See I have an script(diff feature) which compare user configuration to the csv file(our main topology table with all the routers name and config) then send the result(missing commands) to a file.your script is check that file to csv file and finds matching commands and send it to the html file, does it make a scense?

Comment: @user3409828 Ok.. So the diff output is the `Rx.cfg` files?

Comment: Rx.cfg is the router config file, the output would be file 1 the comparison result.

Comment: what you see in file 1 is the commands which user have missed (as a result of diff output comparison)

Comment: @user3409828 Ok, great.. Then you have to change the names in the bash script.. since I misunderstood.. I mean change `R1.cfg` to `file1` for instance..

Comment: Ok thats make a scenes, what about sending the result to the html table(file), I found this commands to Find a word and replace it `sed 's/old/new/g' Lab-console.html` second one is to Find a word and show characters after that `grep -oE 'config.{5}' R1.cfg` but i know they are different features

Comment: @user3409828 Yes the commands seems good, but first we need to find a method to calculate **where** in the html file we should do the replace

Comment: In a normal practice if I add anything after the word config in html file would it shows those characters in the table in html file?

Comment: @user3409828 I am not sure about that.. What do you mean by `add anything after the word config in html file` ?

Comment: I mean the exact location to paste the result(in file 1). I am doing it right now to see if it add the characters in the table, when i modify and save the html file and reopen it again

Comment: @user3409828  Concerning the csv file: Will ID always be row number 3, and Config will always be row number 4, and so on?

Comment: I thought Id is column 2 and config is column 3

Comment: @user3409828 Regarding the html file: Will there be more than one table?

Comment: @user3409828 And note the difference between row and columns.. I am talking about row numbers

Comment: Actually I was about saying to give you the complete html file, where should i paste it?

Comment: @user3409828 Good, try http://pastebin.com/ Or you could email it to me, if you prefer..

Comment: @user3409828 It's on my SO profile.. Just click my name.. ( `hakon.hagland@uni.no` )

Comment: Have you received it?

Comment: I sent to hakon.hagland@uni.no - I also pasted it in pastbin.com its called html file

Comment: @user3409828 I got it now! So it is this line: `<tr class="gwd-tr-rtto">`? At line 475

Comment: @user3409828 But there are two empty tables below also..`gwd-tr-aavl` and `gwd-tr-g7t9`

Comment: Yes the missing commands are seating in those columns, what is gwd-tr-g7t9 ?

Comment: @user3409828 Yes.. `gwd-tr-g7t9` is the second row in the table

Comment: @user3409828 So you want to insert the missed commands in the first row? But what is the purpose of the second row then?

Comment: each row is for one device with a hostame (R1), and I have to add more rows till it match the number of devices in the topology

Comment: @user3409828 Ok, I have to take a break now.. I can help you tomorrow, if you like?

Comment: or for example if we have 2 missing command in R1 then will have 2 rows with hostname R1 with two missing commands

Comment: I appreciate your help, its nice to see some people spend times to help others now adays. just let me know when tomorrow and i`ll be here

Comment: Thanks, it is an interesting problem.. I will be available after 11 am, CET tomorrow. See you .

Comment: @user3409828 Good morning!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50011/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-user3409828)